# Login React Native MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, react-native, fetch

We been having an issue with our login code. We keep receiving an SyntaxError: JSON Parse Error:

[image]

We narrowed down the response error happens during one of the .then(response) lines or in the php code. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help?!

loginScreen.js

```
login = () =>{
    const { UserEmail }  = this.state ;
    const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;

    fetch('http://localhost:65535/login.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user_email: UserEmail,
        user_pass: UserPassword
      })
     //Error within line 59-61 or php
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        // If server response message same as Data Matched
        if(responseJson === 'Data Matched'){
            alert("Correct");     
        } else{
            alert("Incorrect");
        }

     }).catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
     });

}


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.container}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
          <View style={styles.welcomeContainer}>
            <Image
              source={
                __DEV__
                  ? require('../assets/images/HootLogo.png')
                  : require('../assets/images/robot-prod.png')
              }
              style={styles.welcomeImage}
            />
          </View>
```

login.php Seems like everything is laid out correctly and works functionaly. I tried changing ' to ` and everything.

```
<?php

 // Importing DBConfig.php file.
 include 'DBConfig.php';

 // Creating connection.
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 // Getting the received JSON into $json variable.
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

 // Populate User email from JSON $obj array and store into $email.
 $user_email = $obj['user_email'];

 // Populate Password from JSON $obj array and store into $password.
 $user_pass = $obj['user_pass'];

 //Applying User Login query with email and password match.
 $Sql_Query = "select * from wp_users where user_email = '$user_email' and user_pass = '$user_pass' ";

 // Executing SQL Query.
 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));


 if(isset($check)){
     $SuccessLoginMsg = 'Data Matched';

     // Converting the message into JSON format.
     $SuccessLoginJson = json_encode($SuccessLoginMsg);

     // Echo the message.
     echo $SuccessLoginJson ; 

 } else{

     // If the record inserted successfully then show the message.
     $InvalidMSG = 'Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again' ;

     // Converting the message into JSON format.
     $InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);

     // Echo the message.
     echo $InvalidMSGJSon ;

 }

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Full JS Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  Input, 
  Platform,
  Button,
  Keyboard,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';



export default class login extends Component {
    static navigationOptions= ({navigation}) =>({
          title: 'Login',   
          headerRight:  

          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
            style={{backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7'}}>

          </TouchableOpacity>
    });  
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            userEmail:'',
            userPassword:''
        }
    }

    login = () =>{
    const { UserEmail }  = this.state ;
    const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;

    fetch('http://192.168.0.13:65535/login.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({

        user_email: UserEmail,

        user_pass: UserPassword

      })

    }).then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {

            // If server response message same as Data Matched
           if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
            {

                //Then open Profile activity and send user email to Home After Login. 
                alert(responseJson);

            }
            else{
              alert(responseJson);
            }

          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });

      }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.container}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
          <View style={styles.welcomeContainer}>
            <Image
              source={
                __DEV__
                  ? require('../assets/images/HootLogo.png')
                  : require('../assets/images/robot-prod.png')
              }
              style={styles.welcomeImage}
            />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.errorContainer}>    
            <Text style={{padding:10,margin:10,color:'red'}}>{this.state.email}</Text>
          </View>


          <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text style={styles.headerText}>Username</Text>
          </View>

          <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter Email"
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={userEmail => this.setState({userEmail})}
          />

          <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text style={styles.headerText}>Password</Text>
          </View>

          <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          style={styles.input}
          secureTextEntry
          onChangeText={userPassword => this.setState({userPassword})}
          />

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}
          onPress={this.login}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.loginText}>Don't Have an Account?</Text>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.emailButtonContainer}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Links')}>
              <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>


      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },

  contentContainer: {
    paddingTop: 10,
  },

  welcomeContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  welcomeImage: {
    width: 250,
    height: 230,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginLeft: -10,
  },

  errorContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      marginTop: -55,
      alignSelf: 'center',
    },

  headerText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'rgba(96,100,109, 1)',
    lineHeight: 24,
    marginLeft: 50,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },

  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
    borderBottomWidth: 3,
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 50,
  },

  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#78AA3A',
    padding: 15,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 50,
    borderColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius:10,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },

  buttonText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
  },

  loginContainer: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },

  loginText: {
    marginLeft: 80,
    marginBottom: 20,
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 19,
  },

  loginButtonText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#78AA3A',
    paddingLeft: 5 
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('login', () => login);
```

Comment: Did you check if UserEmail or UserPassword are getting the correct value from the state? Please put your JSX codes too to clarify the question more.

Comment: Yeah I commented out the entire .then(response) and the if/ statements and put in an alert retrieving the inputed values. The values that I inputed when I hit submit are returned in the alert statement.

Comment: Can you please post your JSX code?

Comment: I added the full JS code to the question. Is that what you are asking for or is JSX something else

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the issue is that your PHP server does not return valid json. It returns a string, even though you do json_encode the string, the string will either be `"Data Matched"` or `"Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again"`. However, when you make the fetch request and do

```js
.then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
```

It attempts to parse the string "Data Matched" when you do `response.json()).then((responseJson)` the .json() part is trying to parse the string that is invalid JSON. So you can resolve this in two ways actually send valid json back from the php server build an object like this `{ "success" : true, message :"Data Matched"}` or simply remove the .json() chain, so then javascript will return a string and not try to parse it as JSON. So without the .json() it will be

```js
...
.then((response) => {
           // If server response message same as Data Matched
           if(response === 'Data Matched')
            {
             alert(response);
            } else {
              alert(response);
            }
...
```

Simply try removing `.then((response) => response.json()` part on line 58 first, and skipping directly to the next chained then clause

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to try change the code

```
fetch('http://localhost:65535/login.php'....
```

to your ip, check your local ip using **ipconfig**
and change the code like this

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.1/login.php'....
```

> sample ip